# Is there a Laravel Relationship that can match this distant relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

With the following table structure...

`Contact`

- id

`Tag`

- id

`ContactTag`

- id
- contact_id
- tag_id

`List`

- id

`ListTag`

- id
- list_id
- tag_id

`ContactListTag`

- contact_id
- list_tag_id

Is there a Laravel relationship that can give me `ContactTags` based on Contacts added to Tags on a List (mouthful)? So I need to match `ContactTag.contact_id` with `ContactListTag.contact_id` and `ContactTag.tag_id` with `ListTag.tag_id` via `ContactListTag.list_tag_id`.

The below gives me what I need, but wondering if there is an easier way.

```
$listContacts = [];
foreach ($list->tagContacts()->with('listTag.tag')->get() as $tagContact) {
    $listContacts[] = ContactTag::select('id')->where('contact_id', $tagContact->contact_id)->where('tag_id', $tagContact->listTag->tag->id)->first()->id;
}
```

Can I get the same result with a `$list->contactTags()` or `$list->tagContacts()->contactTags()` relationship?

For reference, below is `tagContacts()` for my working code:

List Model:

```
public function tagContacts(): HasManyThrough
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        ContactListTag::class,
        ListTag::class,
        'list_id',
        'list_tag_id',
        'id',
        'id'
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll not lie to you, I've read your question ten times and I'm lost between the tags, contacts and lists. I understand that's a distant and complicated relationship.

Sadly, Laravel doesn't not provide these kinds of distant relationships.

However, there is a package designed to solve these problems: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

*Quick disclaimer, I'm not the author of this package, I'm using it when I need complex relationships and it works well.*

Comment: Hehe yes it's a little complicated. Basically you create a contact, Steve, and add the tag Pool keeper for him (ContactTag relationship). Now you create a list and you add the tag Pool keeper there as well (ListTag relationship). Now you add Steve to the pool keeper tag on that list (ContactListTag). Note that I don't want to add the ContactTag relationship to the list, but I now do want to be able to retrieve all ContactTags based on that list. If I need a 3rd party package I may just go with the solution I have. I tried some join solutions, but couldn't figure out how. Thanks for your time!!